# Performance impact of HDFS dfs.replication factor

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication, hortonworks-data-platform

I have few questions over hdfs replication factor.

There is a Hadoop cluster in which the replication factor is set to the default value 3. We have some issues with disk space so some guys suggested to reduce the replication factor to 2.

Does this approach really save the disk space?

What would be the read/write performance impact of this?

Comment: Found some useful facts here: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/76966/hdfs-block-replication-dfsreplication-affect-perfo.html